# Passing an argument to a EXE python function built with pyInstaller

Tags: function, arguments, exe, pyinstaller

I have the following simple function which compiles perfectly well with pyInstaller.  The little function runs perfect at the python shell, for the filename `printString.py`

Code within the above filename:

```
def prnt(inStr):          
        print inStr
```

In order to execute  in the python shell:

```
import printString

printString.prnt('myString')
```

Which produces output:

```
myString
```

How do I run the resultant `printString.exe` produced from pyInstallerr passing the the string argument `myString` to the EXE in a Windows 7 command window?

OS platform:  Windows 7 64 Bit.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the function in your .py file if you want the .exe to do anything.

```
def prnt(inStr):          
    print inStr

prnt("string displayed by exe")
```

Comment: J. Wolfe, thank you and understood.  I have studied argparser tutorial now, and, better understand how to structure a function and an input argument.  Your feedback was very helpful.  Thank you.